# ObjectMapper truncates dates in Map

Tags: java, serialization, java-time, objectmapper

I have an `ObjectMapper` that is configured with the following `DateTimeFormatter`:

```java
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ").withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

I want to convert a map with `OffsetDateTime` in it to json. My problem is that apparently `OffsetDateTime` is converted correctly when it is the value

```java
Map<Integer, OffsetDateTime> map = ImmutableMap.of(1, offsetDateTime);
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(map));
// {"1":"2019-03-20T16:46:00.000+0000"}
```

but not when it is the key

```java
Map<OffsetDateTime, Integer> map = ImmutableMap.of(offsetDateTime, 1);
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(map).toString());
// {"2019-03-20T16:46Z":1}
```

Notice that the seconds and milliseconds were truncated. I have tested this with other maps, like `HashMap` or `TreeMap`, with the same results.

This is the definition of the `ObjectMapper`:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
mapper.setDateFormat(DateConstants.SIMPLE_DATE_FORMATTER);
mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());

SimpleModule instantModule = new SimpleModule();
instantModule.addDeserializer(OffsetDateTime.class, new OffsetDateTimeDeserializer());
instantModule.addSerializer(OffsetDateTime.class, new OffsetDateTimeSerializer());

mapper.registerModule(instantModule);
mapper.registerModule(offsetDateTimeModule);
```

and this serialiser:

```java
public class OffsetDateTimeSerializer extends JsonSerializer<OffsetDateTime> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(OffsetDateTime value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        String str = DateConstants.FORMATTER.format(value);
        gen.writeString(str);
    }
}
```

**Edit after assylias answer:**

I have now changed my `SimpleModule` to

```java
SimpleModule instantModule = new SimpleModule();
instantModule.addDeserializer(OffsetDateTime.class, new OffsetDateTimeDeserializer());
instantModule.addKeyDeserializer(OffsetDateTime.class, new OffsetDateTimeKeyDeserializer());
instantModule.addSerializer(OffsetDateTime.class, new OffsetDateTimeSerializer());
instantModule.addKeySerializer(OffsetDateTime.class, new OffsetDateTimeSerializer());
mapper.registerModule(instantModule);
```

with `OffsetDateTimeKeyDeserialzer` as

```java
public class OffsetDateTimeKeyDeserializer extends KeyDeserializer {
    @Override
    public OffsetDateTime deserializeKey(String key, DeserializationContext ctxt) {
        return OffsetDateTime.from(DateConstants.FORMATTER.parse(key));
    }
}
```

When `OffsetDateTime` is the value, things continue to work correctly. However if it is the key, I now get

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException: Can not write a string, expecting field name (context: Object)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator._reportError(JsonGenerator.java:1961)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.JsonGeneratorImpl._reportCantWriteValueExpectName(JsonGeneratorImpl.java:244)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.WriterBasedJsonGenerator._verifyValueWrite(WriterBasedJsonGenerator.java:866)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.WriterBasedJsonGenerator.writeString(WriterBasedJsonGenerator.java:368)
    at com.brandwatch.signals.commons.util.jackson.OffsetDateTimeSerializer.serialize(OffsetDateTimeSerializer.java:16)
    at com.brandwatch.signals.commons.util.jackson.OffsetDateTimeSerializer.serialize(OffsetDateTimeSerializer.java:12)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdKeySerializers$Dynamic.serialize(StdKeySerializers.java:225)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeFields(MapSerializer.java:707)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:639)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:33)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:3905)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:3219)
```

**Edit 2:**

This `KeySerializer` seems to have done the trick for me:

```java
public class OffsetDateTimeKeySerializer extends StdSerializer<Object> {

    public OffsetDateTimeKeySerializer() {
        super(Object.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        if (value instanceof OffsetDateTime) {
            String str = DateConstants.FORMATTER.format((OffsetDateTime) value);
            gen.writeFieldName(str);
        } else {
            gen.writeFieldName(value.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have discovered, this only applies the (de-)serializers to values. To apply the same serialization rules to keys, you need a key (de-)serializer:

```
instantModule.addKeyDeserializer(OffsetDateTime.class, new OffsetDateTimeDeserializer());
instantModule.addKeySerializer(OffsetDateTime.class, new OffsetDateTimeSerializer());
```

Note that the key deserializer needs a `KeyDeserializer` object, not a `JsonDeserializer`.

More info in [the javadoc](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/module/SimpleModule.html).

Comment: Thank you! I have tried this, however I ran into a different problem. I have extended my question.

Comment: @YanickNedderhoff I'm not sure what causes the error, but you may want to try extending [`StdKeySerializer`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/std/StdKeySerializer.html) instead of reusing your `OffsetDateTimeSerlializer`.

Comment: Almost, I've updated my answer (Edit 2). This seems to do the trick for now, it's not clear to me why it has to be like that. Seems not obvious to me :/


If you have thought let me know :)

Comment: @YanickNedderhoff I'm not sure to be honest, I have never used key serializers before. Glad you found a way in the end.